# .htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters - apache error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

this is my .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php56 php56 php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
#php_value error_reporting 8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/old/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cmsfolder/index.php [L]Options +Indexes
# RewriteRule ^(?!404\.php)$ - [L,NC,R=404]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]



</IfModule>

order allow,deny
allow from all

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.ir$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.ir$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$  [NC]
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

I got this error from apache error log:

```
[Thu Jan 10 11:39:07.445956 2019] [core:alert] [pid 11045] [client] /home/***/public_html/old/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

Comment: Probably due to the fact that you have two directives on one line there, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]`

Comment: post your comment. your answer is correct.

Comment: Questions like this usually get closed (_“This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.”_), and answering them is actually discouraged.